# How to not make border-bottom push and inconsistency on IE11

Tags: css, html, internet-explorer, border

How can I make it so that my `border-bottom` on hover, does not extend `height` of the parent but maintains it so that everything stays the same except that the `border` is shown?

Also, when checking this out in IE 11, the `border` is not really at the bottom of the parent, but you can see like a `1px` white space in-between. Is there anything I could do to make it work consistently?

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vdptxcg8/)**

**CSS**

```
#main-nav {
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    border-width: 1px 0;
    margin-top: 70px;
    line-height: 38px;
}

.menu {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
}

li {
    float: left;
    color: #666;
    margin-right: 5px;
}

#search {
    float: right;
}

li:hover {
    border-bottom: 2px solid #000;
}
```

**HTML5**

```
<nav id="main-nav">
    <ul class="menu">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Test 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Test 2</a></li>
    </ul>

    <form id="search" action="#" autocomplete="off">
        <input type="text" id="query" name="query">
    </form>
</nav>
```

Comment: You still haven't checked? Then why are you asking here?

Answer (score 0):

To avoid a change in height, simply have the element already start with a border-bottom that is transparent.

```
li {
    border-bottom: 2px solid transparent;
}
```

On mouseover all you need to change is the border-bottom-color:

```
li:hover {
    border-bottom-color: #000;
}
```

> http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EjgJqZ
>
> http://jsfiddle.net/vdptxcg8/1/

I have also added `transition-duration: 0.2s;` for the change to happen in a smooth animated way rather than abruptly.

The 1px whitespace issue you report does not happen here in IE 11.